# Put a "printer spread" PDF into "reader spread"

Tags: pdf

I have some physical documents which are A5-size booklets, which I want to scan. I can remove the staples and scan them flat, but the resulting PDFs are "printer spread", i.e. the pages are in an unnatural order when viewed on screen.

I need to chop up the PDF to split each side into two pages (down the crease line -- picture how a folded leaflet is printed) and re-order the pages to be in the natural order.

Is there any way to automate this?

I have found [briss](https://sourceforge.net/p/briss/code/HEAD/tree/briss/) which can do the page splitting, but not the reordering. I might be able to modify it, (although [this](https://github.com/mbaeuerle/Briss-2.0) fork at least builds from source).

Is there an easier way? Command-line or GUI is fine. Would be handy if I could do it on Linux but I can use Windows if necessary.

Comment: Closed for lack of clarity with no comment about what is unclear. Honestly I think the question is clear but if not, perhaps someone could suggest which part.